# error espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli, nulo

Tags: php, mysql

es para una aplicacion de celular y me sale esto

> Advertencia : mysqli_query () espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli, nulo dado en /home2/prohomeperu/public_html/central/ingreso.php en la línea 11 No se pudo Insertar

```
    <?php
    $connexion= new mysqli("localhost","prohomep_proho","123456789proho","prohomep_central");
    $dni=$_GET["dni"];
    $nombre=$_GET["nombre"];
    $apellido= $_GET["apellido"];
    $telefono=$_GET["telefono"];
    $licencia=$_GET["licencia"];
    $estado=$_GET["estado"];
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `conductor`(dni, nombre, apellido,telefono, licencia, estado) VALUES ('null','$nombre','$apellido','$telefono','$licencia','$estado')";
    $result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    if($result){
        echo "Datos Insertados";
    }else{
        echo "No se pudo Insertar";
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: Es un error tipográfico, que hace que uses una variable inexistente.

Answer (score 2):

el problema que veo en tu código es que al realizar la definición de tu variable

```
$connexion= new mysqli("localhost","prohomep_proho","123456789proho","prohomep_central");
```

es diferente a la que ocupas aqui:

```
$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

En pocas palabras solo vi el error que tienes una n de mas en la palabra conexión.